# Implement notifications icon with message on my web page

Tags: javascript, spring, twitter-bootstrap, notifications, thymeleaf

I created a web portal (using Spring, bootstrap, javascript and thymeleaf) with user login and I would like to use notifications icons for some message.
For example I have an asynchronous task and I would like to set "1" on warning icon if there is an error and show the error message.
Other example is to show a notification to the administrator when he has to do some action (for example enable a user)
I thought to these two solutions:

1. Use a message broker where I can put the error/message with the
   destination users (a user, an administrator or all he
   administrator). So the icon use ajax and rest webservices to
   retrieve information with polling policies.
2. Use the polling and database

There are better solutions?
What are the best practices to do this?

Comment: You have at least these three options available: Polling, Long polling and Websockets.

Comment: Could I store information into database (user,short message, whole message and other) and each icon polling to know if there are message for user in the current session and show it?

Comment: It is called [Server Push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). You can check [Atmosphere Framework](http://async-io.org/tutorial.html) for simple usage example.